# Display Filter Result only if inputs provided - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input

I have an input that will filter out a list of users.

```
<!-- Input -->
<input type="text" ng-model="search">


<div ng-repeat="obj in data | filter:search" ng-show="search.$touched" >

    <div class="row">

        <!-- Country -->
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center" >
            <p>[[obj.country]]</p>
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,[[obj.flag]]" alt="" width="30px">
        </div>

        <!-- Main Info -->
        <div class="col-xs-4" >
            <p class="company-name">[[obj.user.username]]</p>
            <p>[[obj.obj.phone_public]]</p>
            <p>[[obj.user.email]]</p>
            <a href="[[obj.obj.url]]">[[obj.obj.url]]</a></span> <span class="col span_2_of_6">
        </div>

        <!-- Logo -->
        <div class="col-xs-4 pull-right" >
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,[[obj.logo]]" alt="" width="100px">
        </div>

    </div>

    <br><hr>


</div>
```

The filter functionality working great, but I am trying to hide it at first and only show it when the input has been modified.

---

Before adding `ng-show="search.$touched"`

[image]

After adding `ng-show="search.$touched"`

[image]

---

Should I use a different directive ?

Now nothing is displaying ...

Comment: "trying to hide it at first and only show it when the input has been modified", try using `search.$dirty` rather than `$touched` if you want it for when it's been modified, as opposed to interacted with. Otherwise, your code appears to do what you're intending from what you've outlined in your question

Comment: I tried `search.$dirty` - same result.

Comment: Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Apologies, i assumed `$scope.search` had been defined in your controller. Since you're using an `input` element outside of a `form`, trying to access its `modelController` instance is going to be difficult. Instead you could try `ng-show="search"` which is just checking for the presence of any search characters. If you can initialise your `$scope.search` value to be `null` in your controller, you can check `ng-show="search !== null"`, as removing all the characters from the input will return `''` instead of `null`

Comment: `$scope.search` works. :D

Comment: Thanks for your details comments. I learn a lot of it from it.

Answer (score 0):

The key part is : `ng-show="search"` will check for the presence of any search characters

```
<!-- Input -->
<input type="text" ng-model="search">


<div ng-repeat="obj in data | filter:search" ng-show="search" >

    <div class="row">

        <!-- Country -->
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center" >
            <p>[[obj.country]]</p>
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,[[obj.flag]]" alt="" width="30px">
        </div>

        <!-- Main Info -->
        <div class="col-xs-4" >
            <p class="company-name">[[obj.user.username]]</p>
            <p>[[obj.obj.phone_public]]</p>
            <p>[[obj.user.email]]</p>
            <a href="[[obj.obj.url]]">[[obj.obj.url]]</a></span> <span class="col span_2_of_6">
        </div>

        <!-- Logo -->
        <div class="col-xs-4 pull-right" >
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,[[obj.logo]]" alt="" width="100px">
        </div>

    </div>

    <br><hr>


</div>
```